# Does it make a difference in accessibility to show a success message in the same page a form was submitted?

Tags: forms, accessibility

Does it make a difference in screen reader accessibility to show a success message in the same page a form was submitted? Or is it better to redirect to a different page?

Comment: It depends how the page has been built. Content that changes dynamically can be announced to the user through [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "difference".

From a strict WCAG conformance perspective, whether you show a confirmation message on the same page or show on a new page, either is ok as long as you have coded it properly.

If doing it on the same page, use [`aria-live="polite"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) on the container where the message is added so that it'll be read by screen readers automatically.

If you go to a new page, make sure the page <title> is appropriate for the confirmation.

You also might have to think about the "back" button in the browser.  If you go back from a separate confirmation page, does that mean you are back on the form and can change values and re-submit it?  If you go back from the form that has the confirmation message on it, I assume that would just to back to the page that took you to the form.

So you might have to do a little research and possibly user testing to see which is "better".  There might be a "difference" in user experience, but not in accessiblity.

Comment: I don't have a good reason to use another page when there's ways to make it work on the same page, so I'll go with the `aria-live="polite"`. However, it says in [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) that `role="alert"` should be added as a redundancy. I'm actually using Bootstrap which seems to only use `role="alert"` for alerts - wondering if `role="alert"` is enough for my form submission success message.

Comment: i would strongly recommend **not** using `role="alert"` except in cases where you have an urgent message.  a confirmation message is just a "nice to have" and shouldn't be an alert.  the article you mentioned says to **not** have it redundant. you almost always only need `aria-live="polite"` except for critical messages.